# 64-character encrypted text

Tags: encryption, cryptography

can anybody help me please? Which encryption can be this: WTUXVZYEBDEDYVWVYDYVCCBBYYAZYDETAUCDCWXTEWWUYTCEYXBXBFAUTTCXCXDW

And maybe a way to decrypt?

If I'm not wrong, it can't be any kind of hash.

I've already tried Vigenere, Caesar, ROT13, SimpleSubstitution, Playfair and Base64, with no success.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be as programming question.

Comment: This is a cryptography question, and because the cryptography is part of programming, therefore I have asked with the corresponding tags.

Comment: The [tag:cryptography] tag says (emphasis mine): "*Cryptography questions **not directly related to software development** are better asked at [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)*" - you might be better off asking there: they say: "*Cryptography Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software developers, mathematicians and others interested in cryptography.*"

Comment: @WaiHaLee No, [crypto.se] would not be a good place to ask this, because analyzing a data dump is off-topic there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, since ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but you can guess yourself: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Comment: @ArtjomB. - I admit the first time I visited that SE site was today - I only *assumed* it'd be on-topic over there.

Answer (score 0):

The letter frequencies (below) suggest it is a substitution cipher:

```
   9 Y
   7 C
   6 X
   6 W
   6 T
   6 D
   5 E
   5 B
   4 V
   4 U
   3 A
   2 Z
   1 F
```

Comment: substitution cipher with only 13 characters?

Comment: The middle (almost exactly) of the alphabet (g->s) is missing

Comment: It's short, you can make a lot of 64 character sentences with only 13 unique letters.